# OpsHub version 2.2.2.001: OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No files checked in

Tags: azure-devops, opshub, tfs-migration

The migraion of the project from TFS 2015 (14.0.23128.0) to VSO is stopped with a failure:

> OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No files checked in.

The issue is reproduced several times.
Is there some workaround?
We use the OpsHub version 2.2.2.001.

A sample of a log file:

```css
2016-05-19 15:57:52,990 [22] WARN  Non-fatal failure: The item $/Extensions/Administration/ME2/Views/TreeView.ascx.cs could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.
2016-05-19 15:57:52,990 [22] DEBUG Actually Editing - 69 files from 70 processed.
2016-05-19 15:57:53,053 [22] DEBUG Resolving conflict - Sanity Run for 0 with result False
2016-05-19 15:57:53,053 [22] DEBUG Preparing checkin: Pending changes completed.
2016-05-19 15:57:53,053 [22] DEBUG Fetching Work Items for ids: 
2016-05-19 15:57:53,053 [22] DEBUG Performing checkin
2016-05-19 15:57:53,131 [22] DEBUG Performing checkin to the TFS workspace
2016-05-19 15:57:53,177 [22] DEBUG [De-bug]No conflicts found through querying
2016-05-19 15:57:53,177 [22] DEBUG [De-bug]Evaluating Checkin before actual checkin
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug]Conflict Count: 3
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Message:The item $/Extensions/Externals/AO/Dev already exists.
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Is Resolveable?:True
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Item:$/Extensions/Externals/AO/Dev
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Message:The item $/Extensions/Externals/AO/Dev/Extensions.Tests already exists.
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Is Resolveable?:True
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Item:$/Extensions/Externals/AO/Dev/Extensions.Tests
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Message:The item $/Extensions/Externals/AO/Dev/Extensions.Tests/Test Site Backup already exists.
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Is Resolveable?:True
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Item:$/Extensions/Externals/AO/Dev/Extensions.Tests/Test Site Backup
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug]Note Failures Count: 0
2016-05-19 15:57:53,724 [22] DEBUG [De-bug]Policy Failures Count: 0
2016-05-19 15:57:56,568 [22] DEBUG Exception in thread of CheckinALL process.
2016-05-19 15:57:56,693 [14] ERROR Error occurred in thread of CheckinAll:TF10141: No files checked in: resolve the conflicts and try again.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Client.ReportCheckInConflictsFailuresAndThrow(Workspace workspace, CheckinResult checkinResult, Failure[] conflicts, Failure[] failures, Boolean noAutoResolve, Int32 operationId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckInInternal(WorkspaceCheckInParameters parameters, Int32 operationId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckIn(WorkspaceCheckInParameters checkinParameters)
   at Service.Adapters.TFSCheckinWorkspaceContext.checkin(String comment, WorkItemCheckinInfo[] workItemChanges, List`1 otherCheckInProperties, String checkinUser) in d:\viral\checkout\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSVersionControl\AdapterComponents\TFSCheckinWorkspaceContext.cs:line 2691
   at Service.Adapters.TFSVCAdapter.checkIn(List`1 checkinItems, String checkinComment, String checkinUser, List`1 workitemId, List`1 otherCheckInProperties, String uniqueId) in d:\viral\checkout\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSVersionControl\AdapterComponents\TFSVCAdapter.cs:line 125
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWebService.<>c__DisplayClass6.<CheckInAll>b__4() in d:\viral\checkout\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWebService.cs:line 1034
2016-05-19 15:57:56,693 [14] ERROR Error : TF10141: No files checked in: resolve the conflicts and try again.
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWebService.CheckinAllStatus(String authToken) in d:\viral\checkout\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWebService.cs:line 1078

2016-05-19 15:57:56,834 [14] DEBUG Getting all changesets that were created after + 17070
2016-05-19 15:57:56,896 [14] DEBUG Retrived total 0 changesets created after 17070.
2016-05-19 15:57:56,990 [14] DEBUG Logout successful for token 08f114ed-16fb-4416-8e2a-44bef80f809f
2016-05-19 15:57:57,006 [14] DEBUG Logout successful for token d1695d71-3d52-4154-b63c-627f5cbb1764
```

Comment: Hi, what is the changeset timestamp? Was it done when your TFS version was TFS 2008?

Comment: Hi, the changeset timestamp is October 08, 2014. Probably it was done with TFS 2012.

Comment: Can you please share the entire set of logs to ovsmu@opshub.com, we'll have to analyze this issue.

Comment: Shared all logs. Thanks